# How to redraw a screen in Android

Tags: android-layout

I want to know how I can for a screen to redraw it's current content?

What I have at the moment is the following: I have an activity that checks if a flag is set to true or false, if the flag is true it needs to load one xml file as it's layout, if the flag is false it needs to load a different one. This code works.

The problem I have is that the screen does not redraw itself unless I change the orientation of it, aka I flip the phone. I need the redraw to happen the moment the state of the flag changes. I had this working with the onResume(), but the problem with that was that the layout went back to the default state and did not save any input or button changes that had been made, this happened when I switched from one tab to the next.

So I guess what I am asking is something along the lines of how I can make changes to a layout file and keep them when switching between tabs in my application, so that when I go back to that tab, all the changes are still there?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you you an AsyncTask waiting in background for your flag to become true (or false idk), then onPostExecute you can modify your UI as you wish. Switching between tabs shouldn't make your Activity change. Hope it helps.

```
private class WaitMyFlag extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while(!youflag){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't sleep !");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
protected Void onPostExecute(Void params) {
        //UI Modifications
    }
}
```